# How to combine 2 columns from 2 tables and subtract duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have 2 tables t1 and t2. Each have a customer ID column. What I am looking for is to join the 2 columns and SUBTRACT the duplicates.

My EG:
[Table1 and Table2 with the IDs for each](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPDPf.png)

I have tried a union query.  The result I am left with is ID = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.  Where, what I'm after is subtracting 1-5 from Table2 and the result = 6,7,8,9,10.

I hope that makes sense and that someone is able to help.  Sorry if this is a bit too simple compared to what you're all used to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server you can use the EXCEPT operator:

```
select ID
from Table2
except
select ID
from Table1
```

Mysql does not support it though.  Using a an in clause or a left join would work in both servers:

```
--Using In clause
SELECT ID
FROM Table2
WHERE ID NOT IN 
(
    SELECT ID
    FROM Table1
);

--Using join
SELECT Table2.ID
FROM Table2
left join Table1
on Table2.ID = Table1.ID
where Table1.ID is null
```

Comment: Fantastic.  Thanks to you both for your help but Brian's solution (Mysql - I should have mentioned that) worked like a charm for me on this occasion!  Awesome.  Thanks again

Answer (score -1):

Use left outer join

```
select * from t1 left outer join t2 on t1.customerid = t2.customerid
```